# What is an Efficient way to load apk icons in Android?

Tags: android, memory, bitmap, apk

I am working on a small file manager that is helping me learn android development and I ran into a few issues with loading apk icons for apk files. I am trying to load the icon that is assoicated with the apk. I am planning on loading it in my adapter.

Here is the method I am using:

```
  public Bitmap getApkBitmap(File f) {
        PackageInfo packageInfo = getContext().getPackageManager().getPackageArchiveInfo(f.getAbsolutePath(), PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        ApplicationInfo appInfo = packageInfo.applicationInfo;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 8) {
            appInfo.sourceDir = f.getAbsolutePath();
            appInfo.publicSourceDir = f.getAbsolutePath();
        }
        Drawable icon = appInfo.loadIcon(getContext().getPackageManager());
        Bitmap bmpIcon = ((BitmapDrawable) icon).getBitmap();
        return bmpIcon;
    }
```

**Problem:**

It works ok, but the problem is that whenever I have a lot of apks, or I scroll a little too fast, the app crashes and I run into a few memories. Plus whenever I am scrolling, its very laggy and isn't smooth at all.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to implement a lazylist to show the images on demand. That could solve your memory problem.

Another thing to consider is to scale the images down if they are too big. That could solve the laggy list problem.